# gcc build error: Trouble closing elf file

Tags: gcc, g++

I’m compiling GCC on Solaris x86 and got the following error:

```
Assembler: optimize.c
    "/var/tmp//ccMndPR3.s", line 85111 : Trouble closing elf file
```

gmake[3]: *** [cp/optimize.o] Error 1

I downloaded MPC,  GMP and MPFR and extracted them into GCC source directory as mpc,gmp and mpfr directories and configure GCC source with:

```
$ ../gcc-5.2.0.src/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-5.2.0 --enable-languages=c,c++
```

I used gmake for executing the compilation tasks.

```
$ gmake
```

The file mentioned in the error message doesn’t exist.

```
$ ls -l "/var/tmp//ccEtAJ5n.s"
/var/tmp//ccEtAJ5n.s: No such file or directory

$  ls -l "/var/tmp/ccEtAJ5n.s"
/var/tmp/ccEtAJ5n.s: No such file or directory
```

I’m not sure how this can happen.

The file system has plenty of room:

```
$  df -h /var/tmp
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s6       99G    27G    71G    28%    /var

$  uname -a
SunOS sbdsvrwm566 5.10 Generic_150401-20 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

the only error message in config.log is as follows:

```
configure:5091: g++ -o conftest -g -O2   -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc conftest.cpp  >&5
g++: unrecognized option `-static-libstdc++'
conftest.cpp:11:2: #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
configure:5091: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| #if (__GNUC__ < 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5)
| #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
| #endif
| int main() {}
```

the error apparently is due to the missing space between -static and -libstdc++. however, what is strange is none of the mentioned confdefs.h conftest.cpp exist either under the source or build directory or installed packages.

obviously the older gcc was used to compile the new gcc:

```
configure:4074: checking for gcc
configure:4090: found /usr/sfw/bin/gcc
configure:4101: result: gcc
configure:4330: checking for C compiler version
configure:4339: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.



$  echo $PATH
/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/bns/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:


$  echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/SUNWspro11/SUNWspro/prod/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/X11
```

Comment: Curious: I've not seen a problem like that.  Do you know which phase this is in?  Is it the bootstrapping phase 1, where it is using some non-GCC compiler (or, more accurately, not necessarily GCC compiler) and toolchain to build the compiler?  Or is it in a later phase?  Are you using the assembler and loader from `/usr/ccs/bin`, or are you using GNU `binutils`?

Comment: from the config.log, I can see the gcc 3.4.3 was chosen in the begining by configure to compile gcc 5.2.0. I'm not sure in which phase it was but it was after >10 hours of compiling. the the assembler and loader from /usr/ccs/bin was used. I updated the post above with new information. thanks.

Comment: It should be at the final phase since I found the final_stage directory was created in the build directory.

Comment: I did a Google search on the error string plus Solaris, and came up with 3 references, one of them this question. The other two were unanswered issues. I'm going to be boring and do what PC Tech Support engineers have recommended since time immemorial: reboot, and try again. Gut feel, it will probably work. If a reboot is out of the question (not your machine, or a shared machine and you can't disturb the others using it, or you can't stop the computation that's 3 months into its 6 month execution cycle, or whatever), then you have to work harder — or find another machine to do the build on.

Comment: I'd like to try using GNU binutils instead of /usr/ccs/bin. any advise on how to specify this?

Comment: (a) Install GNU binutils; (b) Remove `/usr/ccs/bin` from your PATH; (c) try to build again.  Check the build/install instructions — there may also be some other steps needed.

Comment: now I'm getting:               

/usr/sfw/bin/gld: skipping incompatible /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.3/amd64/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc                                
/usr/sfw/bin/gld: cannot find -lgcc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84525/discussion-between-alexl-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am facing the same problem trying to build gcc 5.2.0 on a RHLE with gcc 4.4.7 as a system compiler...